# List devices on local network

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I want to list devices in the same local network in my application. I did a lot of research for this, but I couldn't find exactly what I wanted.

For example:
I have 3 devices connected to a router with a default gateway address of 192.168.1.1. Their IP addresses are 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.8, 192.168.1.10 etc. I want to list the IP address and MAC address, device type (PC, Phone, Printer etc.) of these devices.

I can find IP addresses by scanning with the [lan_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/lan_scanner) library. However, as I mentioned above, I would like to access more detailed information.

As a result of my research, I reached the [multicast_dns](https://pub.dev/packages/multicast_dns) library, but I could not understand how to use it as I wanted.

What roadmap should I follow for this?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try nmap.

nmap -FO [subnet]/[mask] - where -F is enabled Fast mode (subnet scan will take some time otherwise) and -O is for OS guess, this does not always work smoothly but should give you quite decent outputs

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I tried using nmap but got an error "ProcessException: Permission denied". I've done research on using nmap but haven't been able to reach my goal.

Best regards.

Comment: @jimmy - you have to run nmap as sudo (linux and MacOS) or if you're in windows, open your CMD prompt as admin before running it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer or any kind of "magic bullet" software that will be able to absolutely identify what KIND of device a particular IP address belongs to. The only information that you are guaranteed to be able to obtain through an `arp` request is the IP address of the device and its MAC address since MAC address is (I believe) layer 2 of the OSI model and IP address would be in layer 3 and that information has to be made available to a network before a device will be allowed to communicate on a network. But high level information such as the KIND of device that an IP address is assigned to, has no defined standard within the OSI model so that information can be made available at the whims of the company that makes the product.

For example, when I scan my network using nmap, I know that I have a bunch of IP based light switches on my network, but the MAC address apparently is not identifiable by vendor name - yet ALL mac addresses have to have a vendor name assigned to them and I'm sure there are various searchable databases publically available to be able to query any given mac address and get the name of the vendor who owns that MAC address. BUT, it is possible to assign any mac address you want to any ethernet port, and if these light switches have their own custom mac address assigned to them, then identifying the vendor will be impossible.

My point being that unless a device is configured so that you are allowed to interrogate it and find out what it is, you will have no standard way of getting that information since that information is not a requirement of the OSI model or any ethernet protocol standard.

Solar Winds [has a program](https://www.solarwinds.com/ip-address-manager/use-cases/network-scanner) that might give you the best chance of success, but its not free.

nmap is probably the best option in terms of publically available, free software that can interrogate a device on a network because it uses 'best guess' when trying to identify what operating system the device is running, and in some cases, you can get lucky in identifying what kind of device it is based on the operating system that it is running.

Answer (score 0):

These steps will help you:

1. Type `CMD` in the search box and click *Run as Administrator* from the menu.
2. Enter the `net view` command to view devices connected to your network. You will then see a list of devices connected to your network in the output.

Comment: They're asking how to do this in Flutter/Dart, not from the command line.